# Show code snippet with syntax highlighting using prismjs inside webcomponent

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting, lit-element, prismjs

I am trying to show a code snippet using Prismjs for the syntax highlighting.

Some info about the project:

i am using lit-element and i have a code snippet saved as a string, which i want to show on the page with some nice syntax highlighting (using prismjs for this).

This is what the snippet looks like on the store (just a string):

[image: snippet value in Store]

Then inside a component i can render it as a string without problems, but i can't seem to get the syntax highlighting to work.

I am importing the styles and i also import prismjs at the top of the component like this:
`import Prism from 'prismjs'`;

To test, i am rendering the snippet in two different ways: the first one as it is saved on the store, and the second one by using the `prism.highlight()` function.

This is how they look like in the frontend:

[image: Both ways it gets rendered in the frontend]

and this is how i am rendering them in my component:

```
<pre>
   <code class="stage__code language-css">${this._selectedSnippet.code}</code>
   <code class="stage__code language-css">${this._highlightedCode}</code>
</pre>
```

The `this._selectedSnippet.code` gets the value as it is saved in the store.

The `this._highlightedCode` get the value from this getter:

```
get _highlightedCode() {
   return Prism.highlight(this._selectedSnippet.code, Prism.languages.css, 'css')
}
```

On the first one i see the correct snippet on the code block, but prism isn't highlighting it. On the second one i see that Prism added the classes it needs to highlight the code, but it is then rendered as a string (with the new markup added by prism).

Any ideas on how i can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just moments after writing this question i remembered something, which allowed me to fix this problem.

I am writing it here, for the case someone else has the same problem.

lit-html has an `unsafeHTML` directive ([here the documentation](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#unsafehtml)) which allows us to render as HTML instead of a string.
Of course this **should be used carefully**, as it can lead to safety problems.

So i ended up importing this directive like this:

`import { unsafeHTML } from 'lit-html/directives/unsafe-html';`

and then rendering the code block like this:

```
<code class="stage__code language-css" id="codeContainer">
   ${unsafeHTML(this._highlightedCode)}
</code>
```